# return the list with strings with single occurrence

Tags: java, string, list, java-8, java-stream

given list of strings, need to return the list with strings that have no duplication (single occurrence) using java (stream)
I have tried using distinct but it wont get single accurances

Comment: show us some efforts :)

Comment: Please provide the code you wrote, the exact task and state what works and what doesnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get unique values from arraylist in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429119/get-unique-values-from-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: Show what u tried plz.

Comment: this is what I wrote 
data.stream().distinct().count();

Comment: return data.stream().filter(a ->data.count(a)>=2); 
//remove what is have more then one accurance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates (both values) - duplicate values from an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126414/remove-duplicates-both-values-duplicate-values-from-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
List<String> result = Stream.of("A", "A", "BB", "C", "BB", "D")
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                         Function.identity(), 
                         Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getValue() == 1L)
            .map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result); // [C, D]
```

Comment: Or collect into a mutable `HashMap`, call `map.values().removeIf(count -> count >1);` and use `map.keySet()` as result (or copy it into a list using `new ArrayList<>(map.keySet())`)…

Comment: @Holger your mind works in mysterious ways... great suggestion, thank u!

Answer (score 1):

maybe a just got wrong the question but you are filtering entries in the list that are NOT duplicated...

so this can work:
 consider a list where the Strings C# and C++ are the only ones that are not duplicated:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Java", "Java", "Java", "C++", "C", "C#", "C");

Map<String, Long> result = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result);

Map<String, Long> filter = result.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue() == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
System.out.println(filter);
```